# C# .NET DocX Add parallel Images to a .docx File

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, docx

I want to add images to a Word file in C# using the DocX Library. The problem is that I don't know that how I can add 2 images in a row using DocX library.

-> Current Situation

I know how to create a file and I know how to write text in the file and insert images but don't know how to place two images in a row. The documentation of the library is sadly pretty small. Hope you can help me!

For reference please the image, I want the just like layout of the document:

[image]

Comment: How about creating a table 2 x 2 with invisible borders and putting images in each cell?

Comment: Here is a sample code for creating a table in a document with DocX: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/blob/master/Xceed.Words.NET.Examples/Samples/Table/TableSample.cs

Comment: Yeah, that's what I need. Thanks a lot.